# constexpr different exception specifier when splitting definition and declaration

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, constexpr, noexcept

I have the following test piece of code tested on `gcc 4.7.2`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

#ifdef REMOVE_CONSTEXPR_NOEXCEPT
# define CONSTEXPR_NOEXCEPT
#else
# define CONSTEXPR_NOEXCEPT noexcept
#endif

class ConstExpr {
public:
  // Some constructors
private:
  // Some member data
public:
  // Cannot split the declaration if noexcept
  static constexpr unsigned int Int(unsigned int i) CONSTEXPR_NOEXCEPT
#ifndef SPLIT_CONSTEXPR_DECLARATION
  {
    return i;
  }
#else
  ;
#endif
};

#ifdef SPLIT_CONSTEXPR_DECLARATION
constexpr unsigned int ConstExpr::Int(unsigned int i) CONSTEXPR_NOEXCEPT {
  return i;
}
#endif

class NoConstExpr {
public:
  // Some constructors
private:
  // Some member data
public:
  // Cannot split the declaration if noexcept
  static unsigned int Int(unsigned int i) noexcept;
};

// It's OK on normal functions
inline unsigned int NoConstExpr::Int(unsigned int i) noexcept {
  return i;
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "ConstExpr: " << std::integral_constant<unsigned int,
    ConstExpr::Int(5)>::value << std::endl;
  std::cout << "NoConstExpr: " << NoConstExpr::Int(5) << std::endl;
}
```

I get the following compilation output:

```
[matt test] g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp && ./a.out
ConstExpr: 5
NoConstExpr: 5
[matt test] g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -DSPLIT_CONSTEXPR_DECLARATION && ./a.out
main.cpp:28:55: error: declaration of ‘static constexpr unsigned int ConstExpr::Int(unsigned int)’ has a different exception specifier
main.cpp:17:33: error: from previous declaration ‘static constexpr unsigned int ConstExpr::Int(unsigned int) noexcept (true)’
[matt test] g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -DSPLIT_CONSTEXPR_DECLARATION -DREMOVE_CONSTEXPR_NOEXCEPT && ./a.out
ConstExpr: 5
NoConstExpr: 5
```

So my question is:  Is it part of the C++11 spec to be able to split the definition and declaration of `constexpr` functions or is this a `gcc` bug?

Comment: The problem seems to be in `exception specifier`, this means - the `noexcept`, not in `constexpr`, according to me.

Comment: You are correct in that the `noexcept` is the problem, however it only occurs on `constexpr` functions.  I'll update to show that normal functions are fine.

Comment: Probably related: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53473

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53473) bug solves this in `4.8.1`